# Sum in another table plus interval of time

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, external

I tried to make a sql but not know hot make it work.
I got this MySQL DB:

THREAD:

```
*id
-date
-title
-text
-user_id
```

RATINGS:

```
*id
-thread_id
-user_id
```

I need to COUNT the positive rating of a determinate THREAD in a interval of time.
For the interval I used this working SQL:

```
SELECT 
SUM(valor=1) AS total_likes
FROM threads
WHERE date>= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)
ORDER BY total_likes;
```

I tried a INNER join with the THREAD's id's but I think I'm failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
SELECT threads.id, COUNT(ratings.id) AS total_likes
FROM threads
LEFT JOIN ratings ON ratings.thread_id = threads.id
WHERE threads.date >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)
GROUP BY threads.id
ORDER BY total_likes;
```

Per thread, it gives the number of respective ratings for that thread.

Comment: this only show me 1 row. But I got more than 1 threads in the ratings table. :s

Comment: @CarlesCarlesCarles Well, then, it seems that the `WHERE` condition is limiting the results.